# Can I force the argument to `res.write` to be sent as a single chunk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I'm using express' `res.write` method to write chunks back to the requester, but one call to `res.write` doesn't mean the argument passed to it will be received as a single chunk, which makes parsing these chunks much more complicated. Is it possible to force single-chunk messages if I can guarantee that the chunks will always be under a certain sizes (something like 200 characters max)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, TCP connections are streams. So either side should expect packets of any size. Even if you could somehow (easily) force packets of a specific size, you can't assume that the other side will (be able to) send packets of a size that you are expecting or even be able to receive your specially sized packets (depending on the size and all of the hops in between both sides).

Comment: Pretty much. Why do you need packets to be a certain size for the client (I'm assuming browsers here) anyway?

Comment: This is for a node script sending multiple images (to a node receiver) in a single request, each image being preceded by an indication of where to save it (path-image-path-image). Detecting wether a chunk is part of an image or part of an indication of where to save the image that follows would have been much easier if the indication was always a single chunk.

Comment: Why not use something like `multipart/form-data` as the format of the request?

Comment: That might be what I'm looking for! Any good link on how to use that in node land?

Comment: Well, there's at least [request](https://github.com/request/request) for submitting multipart forms and [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)/[busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) or [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty)/[formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for parsing multipart forms.